# how to pass and get id in php

Tags: php, sql

I'm trying get id of a user when click,But right now my code is given error I have done this in my other file it work fine with my code I'm trying to use this code but is not working please some should fix my code

request.php

```
<?php

include 'db.php';
if(isset($_GET['id'])){
    $id = $_GET['id'];

$sql = $con->prepare("select * from alert_users_account where id=?");
$sql->bind_param('i',$id);
$sql->execute();
$result = $sql->get_result();
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();

echo $row['id'];

}else{
echo 'error';

}
?>
```

user.php

```
<div class="users_b">
     <?php
     include 'db.php';

        $sq = "select * from alert_users_account";
        $query = mysqli_query($con,$sq);
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);

     ?>

     <form action="request.php" method="post">
     <a href="request.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']?>">
     <input type="submit" value="ADD" readonly></a>
     </form>
     </div><?php }?>
     </div>
     </div>
```

i want to pass the id of the user when submit button is click and get the id in request.php

Comment: POST != GET ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The part where you went wrong is in the request.php itself.

You need to trigger a `POST` in order to trigger the action.

```
<?php

include 'db.php';
if(isset($_POST['id'])){
$id = $_POST['id'];
$sql = $con->prepare("select * from alert_users_account where id=?");
$sql->bind_param('i',$id);
$sql->execute();
$result = $sql->get_result();
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();

echo $row['id'];

}else{
echo 'error';

}


?>
```

This will ensure upon clicking , it will trigger to run the back-end query.

Answer (score 0):

Your form use the POST method and you're trying to access the $_GET variable. You should do:

```
if(isset($_POST['id'])){
    $id = $_POST['id'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either put `?id=<?php echo $row['id']?>` inside the `action` attribute of your `form` tag or do what Gwaldhorf Miopau told in his/her answer, but keep in mind that you have to give the `a` element inside your `form` tag a `name` attribute with the value "id".

Answer (score -1):

1. `$id = intval($_GET['id']);`
2. Use prepare statement

   ```
   $db = $pdo->prepare(' SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `alert_users_account` WHERE `id`=:id  ');
   $db->bindParam(':id', $id);
   $db->execute();
   $Users = $db->fetchAll();
   ```
3. Use try/catch to see errors

   ```
   try {
   $db->execute(); } catch (PDOException $e) {
   echo '<pre>';
     print_r($e->getMessage());
     $db->debugDumpParams();
   echo "</pre>"; }
   ```